# Select & retrieve multiple rows from a sorted datatable in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, row-number

Using https://demo.shinyapps.io/029-row-selection/ as reference, I am building an app to select any number of rows in a sorted/unsorted data & retrieve the corresponding indices. However if I use the code *as is*, it does not work on sorted data. So I changed the code as follows:

> server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$tbl <- renderDataTable(
    mtcars,
    options = list(pageLength = 10),
    callback = "function(table) {
      table.on('click.dt', 'tr', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        Shiny.onInputChange('rows',
                            table.rows('.selected').data()[0][0]); # returns actual row number but does not allow multiple selection
      });
    }"
  )
  output$rows_out <- renderText({
    paste(c('You selected these rows on the page:', input$rows),
          collapse = ' ')
  })
})
```

> ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(   title = 'Row selection in DataTables',   sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(textOutput('rows_out')),
    mainPanel(dataTableOutput('tbl')),
    position = 'right'   ) ))
```

So I use `Shiny.onInputChange('rows',table.rows('selected').data()[0][0]);` so that when the table is sorted, it returns the row number in the actual dataset and not the index based on the visible table. But the problem is that it only returns the first selection.

I also tried using `Shiny.onInputChange('rows',table.rows('selected').data()[0][0].toArray());` to get all selected row numbers in an array but strangely it doesn't return anything, not even the first selected row number (like above).

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved in the **DT** package. You will no longer need to write JavaScript. Please see http://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html for examples.

Comment: I am using shiny_0.11. Using the DT package & upgrading to shiny_0.12, I have to change my entire shiny code (this is just a small part of my code) because I saw there are a lot of changes from the previous to current version. But thanks anyway, I will try to update my code.

Comment: @KomalRathi Okay, let me know if you run into any problems when switching to DT.